# Evaluating $\cos(75^\circ)\sin(75^\circ)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The following problem:

$$\cos(75^\circ)\sin(75^\circ)$$

What is the shortcut for this?  Anything besides the sum formula?

Also, is cosine distributive?  For example $\cos(45 + 30)$ ... does this equal $\cos(45) + \cos(30)$?

Comment: $$\sin75^\circ\cos75^\circ=\frac12\sin150^\circ=\frac14$$Cosine is not a linear transformation, so no, $\cos(a+b)\neq\cos a+\cos b$. In fact, $\cos(a+b)=\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b$.

Comment: what is that cheat formula called?

Comment: You have posted $5$ questions within the last $2$ hours with little to no context or effort shown. I don't believe this is what the site is meant for.

Comment: It is one of the duplication formulæ.

Comment: @Bernard What, exactly, is being referred to here?

Comment: Cosine is *not* distributive, as it would imply it is linear, and its graph would be a straight line.

Comment: @DonThousand: The formulæ for $\sin2\alpha$ and $\cos 2\alpha$. Read from  right to left they're also *linearisation formulæ*.

Comment: $\tan(75)\cdot \cos^2(75)$ but that's not so useful.

Comment: $\cot(15)\sin^2(15)$ just looks simpler.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee You do see the solution I posted...

Comment: many ways to get to it.

Comment: You can use the [double-angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle_formulae) for sine, which can be derived from the [angle sum formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) for sine.

Comment: Of course ***not*** distributive $1 = \cos(0) = \cos(0+0) \ne \cos(0) + \cos(0) = 2$

Comment: @skyking: I wrote my answer *before* seeing your comment. We differ in two characters ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Mh, assume the cosine to be distributive. Then we have

$$1=\cos(0)=\cos(0+0)=\cos(0)+\cos(0)=1+1.$$ Magic !

---

By the way, you don't say *distributive* for a function that commutes with addition, you say *linear*.

---

The intended shortcut is by the double angle formula,

$$2\cos75°\sin75°=\sin150°=\sin30°.$$

Answer (score 0):

We know $$2\cos x~\sin y~=~\sin(x+y)~-~\sin(x-y)$$

So $$\cos(75^\circ)\sin(75^\circ)=\dfrac 12\left[\sin(75^\circ+75^\circ)~-~\sin(75^\circ-75^\circ)\right]$$
$$=\dfrac 12 ~\sin 150^{\circ}~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$
$$=\dfrac 12 ~\sin (180^{\circ}-30^{\circ})~$$
$$=\dfrac 12 ~\sin (30^{\circ})~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$
$$=\dfrac 14~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$$

---

---

> Sum and Difference Formula for trigonometric functions:
>
> $$\sin(A + B) = \sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B$$
> $$\sin(A − B) = \sin A \cos B − \cos A \sin B$$
> $$\cos(A + B) = \cos A \cos B − \sin A \sin B$$
> $$\cos(A − B) = \cos A \cos B + \sin A \sin B$$
> $$\tan(A + B) = \dfrac{\tan A + \tan B}{1 − \tan A \tan B}$$
> $$\tan(A − B) = \dfrac{\tan A − \tan B}{1 + \tan A \tan B}$$

Clearly $$ \cos(45^{\circ}+30^{\circ}) \ne \cos(45^{\circ})+\cos(30^{\circ})$$